# My project has include page for every page. Include layout show well designed in include layout. But the owner page don't show same view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Every layouts in project has include layout. I have designed well in iclude layout. But in main layout of include layout don't show same view. for example the buttons move to the right of screen. I did different screen designs for small, normal, large and xlarge. But that didn't solve problem.

```
    activity_login.xml


   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/loginlayout"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/login_arkaplan"
   >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

        <include layout="@layout/login_inner_part" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewForgetPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lostpass"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOrange"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRegister"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
     activity_login_inner_part.xml


     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="20"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorGrey"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Eposta"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="84dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="267dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_userpass"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorGrey"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="84dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="341dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="GÖNDER"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

I don't know why this button move right of screen. I am doing this include layouts first time and I don't know reason of it. I can't solve it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution would be to use `RelativeLayout` to center the button with reference to it's parent instead of giving it a fixed left margin.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="GÖNDER"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: I will try it tomorrow in work. If it will solve I will mark your answer. Thanks for your helping.:)